# Making curved text on coord_polar

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I want make curved text around ggplot with coord_polar. I have data.frame:

```
z <- data.frame( a=c("sensor 1","sensor 2","sensor 3","sensor 4","sensor 5","sensor 6","sensor 7","sensor 8"),  b=c(50, 60, 70, 20,90,110,30,100))
```

And here is code where I create my ggplot:

```
cxc <- ggplot(z, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=factor(b))) + 
    geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity",colour = "black")
cxc + coord_polar() + 
  theme_linedraw() +theme(axis.ticks =element_blank(), axis.text.y =element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(size = 12,angle = 45))
```

Here is image from my result. I want making texts (x axis): sensor 1, sensor 2... making curved like I draw with red color around circle from coord_polar. Must fit with circle. 
[image]

Comment: @Hack-R Maybe yes, but I need produced lot of plots and I think in R better making this. Anyway I think here must be easy solution for curving text.

Comment: Accepted solution is rotation... Did you manage to actually curve the text?

Comment: @zx8754 No. The answer is the closest one solution.

Comment: Please check the new [`geomtextpath` package](https://github.com/AllanCameron/geomtextpath).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure on curving the text, but if you want them to at least rotate, this is a start:

```
myAng <-
  seq(-20,-340,length.out = 8)

cxc + coord_polar() + 
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(axis.ticks =element_blank()
        , axis.text.y =element_blank()
        , axis.title=element_blank()
        , axis.text.x=element_text(size = 12
                                   ,angle = myAng))
```

I will add in my hesitation on using such angles (or even polar coordinates for a plot like this). However, I assume that you have a good reason for doing it, and that this MWE just doesn't show it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The {geomtextpath} package has a dedicated function for exactly this use case, including curved text. See also: [here](https://allancameron.github.io/geomtextpath/articles/curved_polar.html).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath) # remotes::install_github("AllanCameron/geomtextpath")

z <- data.frame( 
  a=c("sensor 1","sensor 2","sensor 3","sensor 4",
      "sensor 5","sensor 6","sensor 7","sensor 8"),  
  b=c(50, 60, 70, 20,90,110,30,100)
)

cxc <- ggplot(z, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=factor(b))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity",colour = "black")

cxc + coord_curvedpolar() + 
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(axis.ticks =element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y =element_blank(), 
        axis.title=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size = 12))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Disclaimer: I'm a co-author of that package.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to make them curve exactly like that using `ggplot2` but we can at least remove the funny angle...

[image]

```
pm <- grid::unit(c(2, 2, 2, 2), "cm")
RadarTheme<-theme(panel.background=element_blank(),
                  plot.title= element_text(size = 25,face=c("bold","italic")),
                  plot.margin = pm,
                  text=element_text(family="Open Sans"), aspect.ratio = 1,
                  legend.position="bottom",legend.title=element_blank(),legend.direction="vertical",
                  strip.text.x = element_text(size = rel(0.8)),
                  axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15,face ="bold"),
                  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.line.x=element_line(size=0.5),
                  panel.grid.major=element_line(size=0.3,linetype = 2,colour="grey"))

cxc <- ggplot(z, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=factor(b))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity",colour = "black")


cxc + coord_polar() + RadarTheme
```