# Why coord_polar can not affect the text in annotate in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Just as the title, and I have a fake data:

```
data <- structure(list(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 
                        2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012), disease = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                                   3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
                                                                                                "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), incidence = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 
                                                                                                                                        0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                "tbl", "data.frame"))

data <- data %>% mutate(disease = as.factor(disease), group =  as.factor(group))
```

The picture in the middle looks like this:

```
p1 <- data %>% ggplot(aes(x = disease, y = year, fill= incidence) ) + 
  geom_tile(color = 'black')+ ylab("") + xlab("") +
 # coord_polar(start=0.11) +
  xlim(c(unique(data$disease), "")) + 
  ylim(c(2005,2012+2)) + 
  annotate(x="",y=2010:2012,label=2010:2012,size=2.5,geom="text")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
    
  ) + 
 geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(disease)-0.5, xend = as.numeric(disease) + 0.5,
                 y = 2009, yend = 2009, group = group, color = group), size = 2) +
geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(disease)-0.5, xend = as.numeric(disease) + 0.5,
                 y = 2014, yend = 2014, group = group, color = group), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#1075BC', '#EE332E')) +
  annotate('text', x = c(1.5, 3.5), y = 2013, 
           label = c('Group 1', 'Group 2'), 
           color = c('#1075BC', '#EE332E'))
```

Then I circular `p1` use `coord_polar()` but the text 'Group 1' and 'Group 2' were not circular as I expected.

```
p1 +  coord_polar(start=0.11)
```

Are there other ways to deal with `Group 1` and `Group 2`?

Also there is another little question: I have two legend, one is `incidence` and another is `group`. How can I just show the `incidence` legend and drop the `group` legend?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi OP - pretty sure you cannot make circularized text in `ggplot` at the moment, as [this would require an add-on package](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2946).   Otherwise, [have you seen this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207390/making-curved-text-on-coord-polar), which seems very similar to your question?  Finally, there does appear to be a way to make some circular text in a polar coordinate plot, through the `circlize` package: [useful reference here](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/introduction.html).  Appears to be base R, not `ggplot2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making curved text on coord\_polar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207390/making-curved-text-on-coord-polar)

Comment: Hi @ chemdork123, I have seen the post in your comment, it does not solve my problem. And I saw `circlize` package, it' s really a handy package and  I will learn it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot natively make curved text in `ggplot2`. However, for short text annotations it is really just a case of rotating your text appropriately. With regards to removing the `group` legend, you just set `guide = FALSE` in the colour scale call that generates it:

```
p1 <- data %>% ggplot(aes(x = disease, y = year, fill= incidence) ) + 
  geom_tile(color = 'black')+ ylab("") + xlab("") +
  xlim(c(unique(data$disease), "")) + 
  ylim(c(2005,2012+2)) + 
  annotate(x="",y=2010:2012,label=2010:2012,size=2.5,geom="text")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
    
  ) + 
 geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(disease)-0.5, xend = as.numeric(disease) + 0.5,
                 y = 2009, yend = 2009, group = group, color = group), size = 2) +
geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(disease)-0.5, xend = as.numeric(disease) + 0.5,
                 y = 2014, yend = 2014, group = group, color = group), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#1075BC', '#EE332E'), guide = FALSE) +
  annotate('text', x = c(1.5, 3.5), y = 2013, 
           label = c('Group 1', 'Group 2'), 
           color = c('#1075BC', '#EE332E'), angle = c(-70, -36), vjust = c(0, 1))

p1 + coord_polar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helps me. BTW, in my real data, I have 7 groups, so I have to find the appropriate angle one by one? Is there an easy way to do this if I have many of groups?

Comment: @zhiweili you could do it with a sequence of equally spaced angles. For example, if you have 7 labels arranged equally around a circle you could have `seq(0, -360, -360/8)[2:8] - 90`. However, this does not account for the white gap in your circle,  so you might need to multiply 360 by about 0.8 to account for this gap, maybe something like `seq(0, -0.8 * 360, -(0.8 * 360)/8)[2:8]`. Also, you would need to space your x values correctly - maybe like `seq(0.5, 4.5, 4/8)[2:8]`